# How can I package type stubs for another package?

Tags: python, mypy

The Python package Flask-HTTPAuth does and likely will not have type annotations ([source](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-HTTPAuth/issues/112)). I would like to create them and provide them as a package on mypy, without forking the project. I've created a [flask-httpauth-stubs package](https://github.com/MartinThoma/flask-httpauth-stubs).

What do I need to do to tell mypy that this package provides the stubs for Flask-HTTPAuth?

### How I test

code.py:

```py
from flask_httpauth import HTTPAuth

def autho(a: HTTPAuth):
    return a.get_auth()
```

Then:

```
$ pip install flask_httpauth flask_httpauth-stubs

$ mypy code.py

code.py:1: error: Skipping analyzing 'flask_httpauth': found module but no type hints or library stubs
code.py:1: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I've also tried renaming the package to `flask_httpauth-stubs` in case the CASE or the dash/underscore matters. Same result.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0561/#stub-only-packages may help you.

Comment: Thank you, @MarioIshac! I've just renamed the package, but it didn't do the trick. I'm out of ideas what I'm doing wrong. I also asked for help in [gitter.im/python/typing](https://gitter.im/python/typing?at=5f7b7f153d3d0d749a2f9b24)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt seems to be otherwise just perfect, but there was a minor error in naming of the Python package that was installed by your stubs distribution package. Since the code is in a Python package named "flask_httpauth" (with an underscore) the stubs must be in a Python package named "flask_httpauth-stubs", i.e. exactly same name with "-stubs" appended.

I created a pull request which fixes your stubs package:
https://github.com/MartinThoma/flask-httpauth-stubs/pull/1

I checked that your example `code.py` can be type checked just fine when the stubs are installed with this minor change:

```
$ mypy code.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```